# Get-AzureRmVM | Export-CSV does not provide Vmsize

Tags: csv, export, missing-data, azure-powershell

When I execute:

```
Get-AzureRmVM
```

It gives the following output:

```
Resource      Group Name  Location   Vm-Size            OsType NIC      State 
XZSANDBOXRG   Jxx         eastus    "Standard_DS11_v2"  Windows jxx360  Succeeded
```

But when I execute:

```
Get-AzureRmVM | export-csv ALLVMdetails.csv
```

It does not provide the `Vm-Size`, instead it gives `VmId`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: You could use `Get-AzureRmVM -status|Out-File test.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command should work for you.

```
Get-AzureRmVM -Status|Out-File D:\test.csv
```

`Get-AzureRmVM` could not get  VMsize.

Comment: @thank you, i tried with the cmdlet unfortunately Vmsize is still missing,also NIC ...

Comment: @techie Sorry for my mistake. I test in my lab again. VMsize and NIC could be select. `Out-File` works for you.

Comment: Thank you Walter, Yes i could get the data, thanks for all the help you have provided, i was wondering if i could add to see  if VM is stopped/deallocated?

Comment: Thanks Walter I had tried two cmdlets Get-AzureRmVM -Status|Out-File C:\test.csv which gives me the status like Name, VmSize,                                                                 when i tried Get-AzureRmVM -Status| export-Csv C:\jbrmvm.csv it gives powerstate  and all other details but misses the VmSize.